# ""CCSprite is not using the same texture id"" workaround?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I am animating a whole body through **SpriteSheets** with **CCSpriteBatchNode and CCSpriteFrameCache**. Now user can add his own pic to that body which when i try to **addChild** to **Spritesheet** crashes with error ***"CCSprite is not using the same texture id"***

Now i know the face **CCSprite** was not in that cache/texture(it was created through **texturepacker**) and the crash was normal but i wanted to know if there was a workaround to this as i have to add a face to that body through user interaction and animate that body. And by far using spritesheets is the best option for animation. anyone??

Answer (score 2):

In this case what you can do is You take picture of user , then you make texture from user's image .
Then Add that texture to the CCTextureCache . Now you have texture of user image. Now you can use that texture in animation.

**Make Texture from Sprite(You can make sprite from user image)**

```
CCSprite *spr = nil;//your sprite
CCRenderTexture* renderTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:spr.contentSize.width height:spr.contentSize.height];

spr.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
spr.position = ccp(0, 0);
[renderTexture addChild:spr];  

[renderTexture begin];     
[spr draw]; // or [spr visit];
[renderTexture end];

CCTexture2D *result = renderTexture.sprite.texture;
```

**Add that Texture in to Texture Cache.**

[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addTexture]

Answer (score 0):

You can not Manually add `CCSprite` to **SpriteSheets**. Because When you create animated Sprite using **texturepacker** then i hope that you know it also created with `.plist` file and it loas image from it with its size.

When you add manually CCSprite then it is nor found from `SpriteFramesWithFile`. may be you got error.

another way for add animated CCSprite without use of  **texturepacker**

```
CCSprite *dog = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dog1.gif"];
        dog.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:dog z:2];

        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for( int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dog%d.gif", i];
            CCTexture2D* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:file];
            CGSize texSize = texture.contentSize;
            CGRect texRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height);
            CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:texRect];
            [animFrames addObject:frame];
        }
        CCAnimation * animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames];
        animation.delayPerUnit = 0.07f;
        animation.restoreOriginalFrame = YES;

        CCAnimate *animAction  = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
        [dog runAction:animAction];
```

Above code is just describe that how can you add animated `CCSprite` without use of  **texturepacker**

Here you can also change array of Images so you may be add manually image also.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `CCSpriteBatchNode` it is linked to a single `texture`. This is the point of a `CCSpriteBatchNode`: to draw different sprites that use the same texture to reduce OpenGL draw calls and increase efficiency.

The easiest workaround (if you have not reached a performance-critical point) would be to use a regular `CCLayer` instead of a `CCSpriteBatchNode`.

If you still want to add different `CCSprites` (say, the body, the limbs and the head of your character) to the same `CCSpriteBatchNode`, the you need to build a single sprite sheet (or texture pack) which contains all the body parts that you need to add to the `CCSpriteBatchNode`. This single sprite sheet will be the only one that the `CCSpriteBatchNode` will use. You won't be able to add `CCSprites` that are not using this sprite sheet.